# Comparing means, having a large variance

Tags: variance, mean

Currently I am working on a project in which i do have two different sample-sets with a limited size and a large variance. Furthermore, I do have a bigger data-set that gives information about the overall variance of the test. I would like to determine whether the two means are the same, taking into account the overall variance. I would like to get some advises how to solve such a problem. Please find a summary of one set of the data below.

**Dataset 1:** Mean=3.68, Variance=5.86  N=31

**Dataset 2:** Mean=4.34, Variance=6.98  N=16

**Overall variance:** 16.9

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: You do not say whether you expect or hope that the two datasets show significantly different means. They don't---not using just the data in the two datasets, nor taking the variance from the larger study into account. See my Answer.

Comment: I always like to inspect a plot of the data points prior to determining the meaning of the summary statistics. Make a graph that show each observed value clustered by dataset and you will easily see why the t-test of BruceET gave a high P-value.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Minitab output below, a Welch two-sample t test, based
on current data (ignoring 'overall variance' from other sources),
shows no significant difference at the 5% level between sample means, P-value
$0.411 > 0.05.$

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample   N  Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       31  3.68   2.42     0.43
2       16  4.34   2.64     0.66

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.660
95% CI for difference:  (-2.279, 0.959)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
    T-Value = -0.84  P-Value = 0.411  DF = 28
```

A pooled two-sample t test, which may be valid here because sample variances
seem similar, also gives P-value about 0.4.

Introducing a larger estimate of population variances from an allegedly
similar situation would only increase the P-value. Using the standard deviation $\sqrt{16.9} = 4.11$ for both groups (in what is essentially a two-sample z test) gives P-value 0.60, far from significant at any reasonable level.

Not knowing details of the 'overall' variance, I would be reluctant to use
it. For example, it could be a mixture
distribution of populations with different means and variances, and hence possibly irrelevant to your experiment.